# mobileFirst Quality library integration technical architecture overview?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

How does the MQA library integrate into the Main mobile application and how does it work in general? 
Where can I find a detaited technical Architecture overview?
(Specialy for xCode and iOS)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the MQA documentation, "[Installing the iOS preproduction libraries]" at :

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/MobileQualityAssurance/index.html#MobileQualityAssurance

We hope this will help.

Kind regards,

Agnès & Yanis

Comment: Hello Agnès & Yanis,

thanks for you feedback this is not a technical architecture overview, this picture is more the common usage architecture, then the technical architecture.

Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Overview page that Agnes and Yanis provided, which outlines the overall process, you can find specific details for installing the MQA library for iOS here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/DownloadingAndInstallingTheIOSLibraries.html. Using the information from this topic, you will see how you can prepare your application in Apple Xcode for reporting on iOS.

Can you please provide more details regarding what you are looking for in a technical architecture overview?

Comment: Like a UML diagram on different levels for concrete components, bindings and so on.

Maybe here like in Jazz.net https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/FoundationArchitecture